# Merging effects in a .stl file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, merge, stl

After merging two DEMs in one, I obtained a .stl file using (DEMto3D complement). In this .stl file I see something like a net where A+B DEMs were merged. The blue zone, only affected by one DEM, its OK. Do you know how can I correct it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like dem A is lower resolution that B.  How are you combining the dems?

Comment: With the Raster>Merge function. Select both DEMs and merge.

Comment: Try merging with the saga tool 'Mosaic Raster Layers'.  It has more options for cellsize and interpolation.  You should be able to get a better result with some experimentation.